# Adding a newline into a string from text file

Tags: c#, text, io

I have a text file.

[image: Example]

I need to add a newline after every new line from text and put every new line surrounded by "" or //.

My Output should be like this:

> //Name    Disengagement point//
>   //Description Automated test case to record
>   disengagement point and force-travel characteristic needed for the
>   point.//
>   //StartRecording  ForceTravel//
>   //UserInteraction Please, start attempting to shift the gear to 1st gear.//
>   //Capture DisengagementPoint  UserInput   ==  1 PressClutch   1   UserInput   ==  1//
>   //UserInteraction Please, shift the gear to neutral.//
>   //ReleaseClutch   100 ForceTravel ==  LimitReleased//

The method for reading text file:

```
if (!File.Exists(measurementPath))
{
    string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(measurementPath);
    foreach (string s in readText)
    {
        script = s.Replace(" ", " // ");
        char[] separator = new char[] { ' ' };
        String[] fields = s.Split(separator);
```

Comment: It is not clear how you specify the places at which you want to break the text.

Comment: Seems like the original text is rather ill-formed... It is hard to check where it must be separated correctly. (For example: check out the first word `point` having no `dot` but must be separated from `Description` - the next word. But then the third `point` is having `dot` as separator). You may want to confirm first if the original text is clean/not clean before you parse/process it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `File.ReadLines`, LINQ + `String.Format` and `File.WriteAllLines`:

```
var newLines = File.ReadLines(measurementPath)
    .Select(line => String.Format("//{0}//", line))
    .ToList();
File.WriteAllLines(measurementPath, newLines);
```